# Two DataGridViews Linking Using DataSet Xml Data

Tags: xml, vb.net, datagridview

Kindly help me in linking two DataGridViews. I have two DataGridViews to display xml file.
I split my data into "two Tables" "BasicData" and "Unbound"
DataGridView1 shows BasicData while DataGridView2 shows linked "Unbound" for each "BasicData" Table shown in above DataGridView.

I tried linking like this:

```
BasicData_BindingSource1.DataSource = dataset_DS1.Tables("set")
BasicData_BindingSource1.DataMember = "BasicData"

Unbound_BindingSource2.DataSource = BasicData_BindingSource1
Unbound_BindingSource2.DataMember = "Unbound"

DataGridView1.DataSource = BasicData_BindingSource1
DataGridView2.DataSource = Unbound_BindingSource2
```

Regards,

I have my xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>

<main xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<set Attr1="Attr1Value" Attr2="Attr2Value">
 <BasicData>
    <Elem1>1.00</Elem1>
    <Elem2>3500.00</Elem2>
    <Elem3>90.00</Elem3>
    <Elem4>90.00</Elem4>
    <Elem5>7140.00</Elem5>
    <Elem6>25.70</Elem6>
    <Elem7>300.00</Elem7>
    <Elem8>2.40</Elem8>
    <Elem9>0.70</Elem9>
    <Elem10>0.83</Elem10>
    <Elem11>0.012</Elem11>
    <Elem12>0.15</Elem12>
 </BasicData>

 <Unbound>
    <DL_FT> 10280.00 </DL_FT>
    <HL_FT> 2000 </HL_FT>

    <DL_FT> 9600.00 </DL_FT>
    <HL_FT> 1950 </HL_FT>

    <DL_FT> 8280.00 </DL_FT>
    <HL_FT> 1900 </HL_FT>

    <DL_FT> 7500.00 </DL_FT>
    <HL_FT> 1800 </HL_FT>

    <DL_FT> 6280.00 </DL_FT>
    <HL_FT> 1600 </HL_FT>

    <DL_FT> 5300.00 </DL_FT>
    <HL_FT> 1200 </HL_FT>

    <DL_FT> 1280.00 </DL_FT>
    <HL_FT> 1270 </HL_FT>

    <DL_FT> 200.00 </DL_FT>
    <HL_FT> 199 </HL_FT>
 </Unbound>      
</set>


<set Attr1="Attr1Value" Attr2="Attr2Value">
 <BasicData>
    <Elem1>12.00</Elem1>
    <Elem2>2999.00</Elem2>
    <Elem3>90.00</Elem3>
    <Elem4>90.00</Elem4>
    <Elem5>50.00</Elem5>
    <Elem6>1000.00</Elem6>
    <Elem7>123.00</Elem7>
    <Elem8>0.123</Elem8>
    <Elem9>0.7</Elem9>
    <Elem10>0.83</Elem10>
    <Elem11>0.012</Elem11>
    <Elem12>0.15</Elem12>
 </BasicData>

 <Unbound>
    <DL_FT>9999</DL_FT>
    <HL_FT>+900</HL_FT>

    <DL_FT>8999</DL_FT>
    <HL_FT>800</HL_FT>

    <DL_FT>7999</DL_FT>
    <HL_FT>700</HL_FT>

    <DL_FT>6999</DL_FT>
    <HL_FT>600</HL_FT>

    <DL_FT>5999</DL_FT>
    <HL_FT>500</HL_FT>
 </Unbound>      
</set>

</main>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  A DGV doesn't automatically update when the datasource changes.  You usually have to set the DataSource to null and then to the DataTable.  Or just add the binding after you fill the DataSet.

Comment: The "Unbound" Table doesn't showing in second DGV DataGridView2.....

Answer (score -1):

Try following xml and see if it works

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<set>
 <BasicData>
    <Elem1>1.00</Elem1>
    <Elem2>3500.00</Elem2>
    <Elem3>90.00</Elem3>
    <Elem4>90.00</Elem4>
    <Elem5>7140.00</Elem5>
    <Elem6>25.70</Elem6>
    <Elem7>300.00</Elem7>
    <Elem8>2.40</Elem8>
    <Elem9>0.70</Elem9>
    <Elem10>0.83</Elem10>
    <Elem11>0.012</Elem11>
    <Elem12>0.15</Elem12>
 </BasicData>

 <Unbound>
    <DL_FT> 10280.00 </DL_FT>
    <HL_FT> 2000 </HL_FT>

    <DL_FT> 9600.00 </DL_FT>
    <HL_FT> 1950 </HL_FT>

    <DL_FT> 8280.00 </DL_FT>
    <HL_FT> 1900 </HL_FT>

    <DL_FT> 7500.00 </DL_FT>
    <HL_FT> 1800 </HL_FT>

    <DL_FT> 6280.00 </DL_FT>
    <HL_FT> 1600 </HL_FT>

    <DL_FT> 5300.00 </DL_FT>
    <HL_FT> 1200 </HL_FT>

    <DL_FT> 1280.00 </DL_FT>
    <HL_FT> 1270 </HL_FT>

    <DL_FT> 200.00 </DL_FT>
    <HL_FT> 199 </HL_FT>
 </Unbound>      
</set>
```

Comment: I shouldn't get negative points for trying a test to attempt to isolate cause of issue.